# Add space between two parts of title format

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec

I'm using the below code for my chapter title formatting to get rid of the "Chapter x" part and put the number on the same line:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}{\thechapter}{0pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}
```

However it gives me this:

[image: Image of chapter title formatting]

Ideally I'd want the "L" of Literature to align with the "I" of Introduction, but I can't find a way of spacing the number and title out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Change the spacing argument `{0pt}` to a more convenient value – more or less something like `{2em}`.

Comment: @Bernard changing it to 1em got the results I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be sure that the titles are aligned, you can set the numbers in a fixed width box.

You may need a larger width if you also have subsections, with a suitable `\titleformat` definition.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}
  {\makebox[40pt][l]{\thechapter}}
  {0pt}
  {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\Large}
  {\makebox[40pt][l]{\thesection}}
  {0pt}
  {}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Literature review}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Bernard in the comments, changing the line to

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{\normalfont\bfseries\Huge}{\thechapter}{1em}{\Huge}
```

aligned the words and fixed the issue.